# Vlookup with partial URL in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have tried several different formula's with this and just no luck. Any suggestions, please..

I have a report in Excel with a list of full url's (Sheet 1). I need to match partial url in B2 on Sheet 1 to the 'Lookup' column on another workbook (OwnerSheet). When a math is found insert the owner

[image]

I have tried several different formula's with this and just no luck. The issue is with matching the partial url. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on your one sample, if you are always only checking the first subpage, this should work:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXTJOIN("/",FALSE,CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(B2,"/"),1,2,3,4))&"/",A4:B5,2,0)
```

Use `TEXTSPLIT` to split the URL by the "/" character

Use `CHOOSECOLS` to only keep the first 4 segments of the URL

Use `TEXTJOIN` to combine the segments again so they match your lookup list. Then you can use any lookup function.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Still no luck.  I don't think I provided a good example or at least one that matched exactly to what I was doing . I updated the original post of a better example with exact  columns and sheet. Anyway, I tried your solution to look to another sheet and couldn't get it to work. Then recreated the original example I provided and followed what you did and got '#NA'.  Any further assistance, much appreciated. I updated the original example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using modern version of Excel (>2019 or 365) you can use XLOOKUP

`XLOOKUP("*"&F12&"*",$D$13:$D$14,$E$13:$E$14,"",2,1)`

Breakdown

1. `"*"&F12&"*"` is the look for which formats the strings in general Excel wildcard search.
2. `$D$13:$D$14` is the lookup range. Best to use is a single column or a row
3. `$E$13:$E$14` return range. Should be equal in size of the lookup range. Otherwise it'll throw an error.
4. `""` If lookup doesn't exist return default value. In this case no value. Default is BLANK.
5. `2` indicates wildcard match. `0` is exact, `1` is exact match or next larger than, `-1` is exact match or next smaller item. Default is `0`
6. `1` indicates top to bottom or left to right. `-1` is reverse of `1`. `2` is sort order smaller to larger and `-2` is reverse of `2`. Default is `1`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  Unfortunately, still no luck. Been at this all day, Couple of issues I had was trying to get it to work looking at OwnerSheet (located on another workbook). Also step 5 - Wildcard match. I updated the original question with a better example with the exact columns and sheets where the content is.  I appreciate the your help. Thank you!

Comment: @RobA. use ```-1``` in step 5 with your specific example and just ```F12``` in step 1- no ```*``` wildcard parameter required.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it is bringing over the value(Owner) regardless if it matches or not.  After your suggestion, this is what I have -  =XLOOKUP(B2,Owner!A:A,Owner!B:B,"",-1,1)  . I appreciate your assistance. Thanks again.

Comment: @RobA., the best way to go about this is to create a column C in sheet 1 that has values derived from B which will make lookup easy. With the data you shared there is no simple formula for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: _ I will give that a try. Thank you so much again for your time and effort on this. Much appreciated.